# Sort 2d array rows by column with values end in clothing sizes/measurements, preserving row indexes

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, custom-sort

My array looks like this:

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 613
        [kleur] => royalblauw/wit
        [maat] =>  maat XL
        [voorraad] => 100
        [sort] => 0
        [prijs] => 4.1320
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 614
        [kleur] => royalblauw/wit
        [maat] =>  maat XXL
        [voorraad] => 100
        [sort] => 1
        [prijs] => 4.1320
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 620
        [kleur] => zwart/wit
        [maat] =>  maat XL
        [voorraad] => 100
        [sort] => 2
        [prijs] => 4.1320
    ) 
       etc.etc.
```

What I want is to sort the array by 'maat' (size). As you can see there are multiple entries with same 'maat'.

This is what I have until now.

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{

$sizes = array(
"116" => 0,
"128" => 1,
"140" => 2,
"152" => 3,
"164" => 4,
"XXS" => 5,
"XS" => 6,
"S" => 7,
"M" => 8,
"L" => 9,
"XL" => 10,
"XXL" => 11,
"XXXL" => 12,
"XXXXL" => 13,
"XXXXXL" => 14
);

$asize = $sizes[$a];
$bsize = $sizes[$b];

if ($asize == $bsize) {
    return 0;
}

return ($asize > $bsize) ? 1 : -1;

}
function aasort (&$array, $key) {
    $sorter=array();
    $ret=array();
    reset($array);
    foreach ($array as $ii => $va) {
        $sorter[$ii]=$va[$key];
    }
    uasort($sorter, "cmp");
    foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va) {
        $ret[$ii]=$array[$ii];
    }
    $array=$ret;
}
```

And calling the function aasort:

```
aasort($maatkleur_array,"maat");
```

Comment: Did you notice some error message? Because your array is like `["maat"]="maat XL"`, but your `$sizes` is like `["XL"]=10`, not `["maat XL"]=10`.

Comment: Hmm I will change it, I did not get an error btw, but sorting isn't working like it should be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to sort an array of arrays. The parent array don't have a (named) key. uasort perserves the key wich you don't want in your case so use usort in stead:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','on');

function cmp($a, $b)
{

    $sizes = array('s'=>0,'m'=>'1','l'=>2,'xl'=>3);

    if ($sizes[$a['maat']] == $sizes[$b['maat']]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($sizes[$a['maat']] < $sizes[$b['maat']]) ? -1 : 1;
}



$input = array(
array('id'=>1,'kleur'=>'blauw','maat'=>'xl'),
array('id'=>2,'kleur'=>'blauw','maat'=>'m'),
array('id'=>1,'kleur'=>'blauw','maat'=>'s'),
array('id'=>2,'kleur'=>'blauw','maat'=>'m'),
array('id'=>3,'kleur'=>'blauw','maat'=>'l')
);

usort($input, "cmp");

print_r($input);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have changed your cmp function little to achieve what you excepting..

```
$sort = array();
// $arrayData is your main array 
foreach($arrayData as $key => $value)
{
   $sort[$key] = cmp(strtoupper(str_replace('maat ', '', $value['maat'])));
}

array_multisort($sort, SORT_ASC, $arrayData);  

function cmp($a)
{

$sizes = array(
"116" => 0,
"128" => 1,
"140" => 2,
"152" => 3,
"164" => 4,
"XXS" => 5,
"XS" => 6,
"S" => 7,
"M" => 8,
"L" => 9,
"XL" => 10,
"XXL" => 11,
"XXXL" => 12,
"XXXXL" => 13,
"XXXXXL" => 14
);


return $sizes[$a];

}
```

sort is based cmp function return value.
$arrayData will have sorted array based on maat size.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to draw some conclusions from your question.

1. You are calling `uasort()`, so you intend to preserve the first level indexes.  This means that `array_multisort()` will not sufffice.  2. Your 2d array has a column called `sort`, so to break ties while sorting, I'll demonstrate how to use that column as secondary sorting values.
2. All `maat` column values begin with `maat` then a space.
3. Your custom priority lookup array is exhaustive and will not change. If so it makes sense to declare it as a constant. Best practice would be to write this declaration in a config-type file - something that can be accessed by many files via `include` -- for convenience/utility/maintainability as a single point of reference.

   ```
   define(
       'SIZES',
       array_flip([
           "116",
           "128",
           "140",
           "152",
           "164",
           "XXS",
           "XS",
           "S",
           "M",
           "L",
           "XL",
           "XXL",
           "XXXL",
           "XXXXL",
           "XXXXXL"
       ])
   );
   ```

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/udmN5))

```
uasort(
    $array,
    fn($a, $b) =>
        [SIZES[substr($a['maat'], 5)], $a['sort']]
        <=>
        [SIZES[substr($b['maat'], 5)], $b['sort']]
);
var_export($array);
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:

Use this callback instead. This will do the trick:

```
<?php
function usort_callback($a, $b) {
        $sizes = array(
            "116" => 0,
            "128" => 1,
            "140" => 2,
            "152" => 3,
            "164" => 4,
            "XXS" => 5,
            "XS" => 6,
            "S" => 7,
            "M" => 8,
            "L" => 9,
            "XL" => 10,
            "XXL" => 11,
            "XXXL" => 12,
            "XXXXL" => 13,
            "XXXXXL" => 14
        );

        $value1 = $sizes[trim(str_replace('maat', '', $a['maat']))];
        $value2 = $sizes[trim(str_replace('maat', '', $b['maat']))];

        return ($value1 < $value2) ? -1 : 1;
    }
?>
```

---

ORIGINAL POST:

Try it with [usort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```
<?php
    function usort_callback($a, $b) {
        return strcmp($a['maat'], $b['maat']);
    }

    usort($array, "usort_callback");
?>
```

Now your array should be sorted by the key "maat"

Comment: But the main thing is that it should not order it on alphabet, I mean for example S should be above L (Small and Large).