# Custom sort on value suffix representing sizes (XXS, XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL)

Tags: php, arrays, usort, suffix, custom-sort

I'm trying to sort my array values by size but I have a problem.
My array pulls out values that are different than the values of the "cmp" function used to sort.
The code is this:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{

    $sizes = array(
        "XXS" => 0,
        "XS" => 1,
        "S" => 2,
        "M" => 3,
        "L" => 4,
        "XL" => 5,
        "XXL" => 6,
    );

    $asize = $sizes[$a];
    $bsize = $sizes[$b];

    if ($asize == $bsize) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ($asize > $bsize) ? 1 : -1;
}

$your_array = array("GL001_XXL", "GL001_L", "GL001_XXS", "GL001_S");

usort($your_array, "cmp");
```

When I try to run this code, it tells me "Undefined key".

How can I sort my array without errors?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: The values in `$your_array` don't match the values in `$sizes`.

Comment: Yes I know. In fact I would to know how I can sort my array by putting first those that have specific characters like XS, then S etc...? Thanks

Comment: If your pattern is `nnn_size`, then you can probably just `explode` on `_` and grab the second item inside of the comparison

Comment: you can use array_pop(explode('_', $a)) to get the size from $a and $b, but be sure to deal with the case where this size isn't in your array.

Comment: Sorry man, where can I put the code of "array_pop"?

Comment: Related: [Sort PHP array by value substring by order in separate array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58315352/2943403) and about sorting with priority: [php sort 2d array by sort order of another 2d array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77326761/2943403) and about ...s/m/l/xl... [Php Array Sorting Clothing Sizes (XXS XS S M L XL XXL) and Numbers on a Dynamic Array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7647982/2943403) and [sort array on clothing sizes (multidimensional array)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16396894/2943403)

Comment: It could be argued that this question's problem is merely a duplicate of [Grab remaining text after last "/" in a php string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2762778/2943403)

Comment: "When I try to print this value" - what does that mean? The code you've shared does not use any `echo` or `printf` or anything else like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments, if your pattern is truly `xxx_size`, you can just explode on the `_` and grab the second item.

The `<=>` can be used whenever you've got the "return 0, 1 or -1" pattern, too.

```php
function sort_array_item_by_size($a, $b): int
{
    static $sizes = [
        "XXS" => 0,
        "XS" => 1,
        "S" => 2,
        "M" => 3,
        "L" => 4,
        "XL" => 5,
        "XXL" => 6,
    ];

    // The next three lines really should include some error checking
    $size_a = explode("_", $a)[1];
    $size_b = explode("_", $b)[1];

    return $sizes[$size_a] <=> $sizes[$size_b];
}

$your_array = ["GL001_XXL", "GL001_L", "GL001_XXS", "GL001_S"];

usort($your_array, "sort_array_item_by_size");

print_r($your_array);

// Array
// (
//     [0] => GL001_XXS
//     [1] => GL001_S
//     [2] => GL001_L
//     [3] => GL001_XXL
// )
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/Dqfi6

Comment: One last question man: if i would create an array from foreach for "static $sizes", how can i do? Thanks again

Comment: @Jackom, I'm not certain what you mean by that?

Comment: I explain to you, I would like the value of $ Sizes to come from a Foreach. This is the example: "static $sizes = $getArrayFromForeach;". How can i do? How should my Foreach be to create the right array for the $sizes variable?

Comment: You mean like this? https://3v4l.org/1c9Cp

Answer (score 0):

I advise against using `usort()` for this task because this involves parsing both strings each iteration (which is more than N times).

Instead, it will be more performant and very concise to use `array_multisort()`.  Because your input strings appear to be consistently padded with zeros, you can simply parse the strings by grabbing the substring starting from the 6th character offset.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/6HH7j))

```
define('SIZES', array_flip(['XXS', 'XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL']));

$array = ["GL001_XXL", "GL001_L", "GL001_XXS", "GL001_S"];

array_multisort(
    array_map(fn($v) => SIZES[substr($v, 6)], $array),
    $array
);
var_export($array);
```

This approach will have the bonus effect of breaking ties (identical size values) by performing natural comparisons on the whole strings.